# Directory Services Com Exception Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to  query LDAP server for a valid credential (username and password). 
The problem is eventhough the credential itself is registered in the server it doesn't get authenticated. 
If i put old ldapPath it works fine.
The code is running on visual studio development server on my local machine (Not IIS).
Whenever i run this i get "Directory Services Com Exception.
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.".

```
const string ldapPath="LDAP:\\newDomain"; //please note this is just an example
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {

            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);


            DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
            {
                SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
                Filter = "uid="+username
            };

            try
            {
                using(HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
                {
                    SearchResult resultEmployee = directorySearcher.FindOne();
                    return resultEmployee.Properties["uid"].Count == 1;
                }

            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
            {
                return false;
            }       

    }
```

Comment: This maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232482/impersonate-with-delegation-or-more-than-one-hop-on-kerberos-completely-lost

Comment: If not, please post the hex error code, that might help.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. here is the hex error code : -2147023570

Comment: I don't actually know much about this, but try Googling "ldap 0x8007052E". That does give some hits.